# Multiple endpoint in Azure function core tools, can workers be assigned to fixed endpoint?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

In Azure Core tools functions, I have different three different Queue Triggered endpoints. Moreover, I have enough resources for four workers. However, I except a very high load on the first endpoint. Is it possible to reserve workers for endpoint two and three ?

Didn't really find any pointer with tackles this problem

Answer (score 0):

> I except a very high load on the first endpoint. Is it possible to reserve workers for endpoint two and three

As stated in [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71867471), though you limit the number of workers for a single function, it does not guarantee that function will be using the defined set of worker processes because they are shared by all of the functions in an Azure Function App/Project based on the load received.

Instead of limiting the worker per function, you can scale out the function app to more instances which distributes the high load among multiple Queue trigger function instances that should has same Queue defined.

Refer to this MS Q&A Issue #[1158258](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1158258/how-to-distribute-the-load-among-workers-in-queue.html) for more ways to manage the load among the multiple Queue Trigger Functions given by @*[Taz-MVP](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/3596370/taz-mvp.html)*.