What is the use of Worker Process Count in Azure - FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT
I was going through Azure function app best practices
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices
and came across the FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT setting
I want to understand the implications of changing this setting with the following example
I have 2 Azure function apps,
1st with 1 Function and Trigger
2nd with with multiple functions and triggers.
Azure Function App1 --> Trigger1
Azure Function App2 --> Trigger1, Trigger2, Trigger3, Trigger4
The function apps are hosted in a premium plan with the following plan

No, I go and increase the value of FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT to 4.
What will be impact of increasing the count?
If there are multiple and concurrent calls to
Case 1. Azure Function App1 - Trigger1
Case 2. Azure Function App2 - Trigger1, Trigger2, Trigger3, Trigger4
--> For Case 1, will Azure allow 4 concurrent calls to Trigger 1 and then scale out to more instances of Function App 1
--> For Case 2, Will Azure allow all the triggers to run concurrently before scaling out to more instances of Function App2
What will the impact of cost in both the cases? (I understand scaling out will cost more)
Will the "Cores" have any impact on this property - FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT?
For this example, please consider .Net 6 with C# as code for the Azure function apps.

The  FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT  setting is used to determine the number of worker processes per host that Azure Functions will use to distribute the function invocations.

Adjust the value of FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT in the Application Settings of Function App to specify how many concurrent instances of your functions can be executed simultaneously.



This setting helps to control the concurrency and scalability of the Function app.

By default, every Functions host instance has a one language worker process and can be increased the processes per host up to 10.
If the FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT set to 4, then Azure Functions will evenly distribute the simultaneous function invocations across all the 4 workers and each host instance will perform 4 individual functions at the same time.

Consider using this setting when the workload has a mix of CPU-bound and I/O-bound invocations.


What will the impact of cost in both the cases? (I understand scaling out will cost more)


The impact of cost depends on the number of instances that are created and the amount of time that they are running.

If the load exceeds the existing instances, Azure will scale out by adding more instances of Function App1 to handle the load.

The impact on cost will initially depend on the number of instances created and the amount of time that they are running.  More instances lead to higher costs due to increase in resource allocation.

The  Cores  will have an impact on FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT property.

For CPU-bound apps, set the number of language workers to be the same as or higher than the number of cores that are available per function app.
When using this property on a Premium or App Service plan, take a note of the number of cores provided by your plan.



Example: Premium plan EP2 provides two cores, so you should start with a value of 2 and increase by two as needed, up to the maximum.

References:

FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71869418


